# Typescript - access class fields from within a class annotation

Tags: typescript, vue.js

With the following code:

```
@Component({
    props: {
        value: String
    },
    mounted() {
        //Do something with `bar`
        this.bar = this.bar + " is now mounted";
    }
})
export default class Foo extends Vue {
     private bar : string = "This element";
}
```

You get the following error in the typescript console, but the code runs fine otherwise.

```
37:14 Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
    05 |    mounted() {
    06 |        //Do something with `bar`
    07 |        this.bar = this.bar + " is now mounted";
       |             ^
    08 |    }
    09 | })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a type-parameter to the class `Component` annotation so that the compiler knows that `this.bar` does exist.

```
@Component<Foo>({
    props: {
        value: String
    },
    mounted() {
        //Do something with `bar`
        this.bar = this.bar + " is now mounted";
    }
})
export default class Foo extends Vue {
     private bar : string = "This element";
}
```

This code compiles with no errors.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Oops, yes I did. Fixed it now, thanks. The question code wasn't supposed to have `<Foo>`